# How to test LIDT instruction in assembly language with Fedora16?

Tags: linux, assembly

I am using Fedora16 and i want to set the address in IDT register using LIDT assembly instruction.So, If i test this in terminal of Fedora16 , it leads to system internal changes or not ?? Is there any other way to test ??

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to change the IDT register while another kernel (Linux in your case) is running. I can easily make the system hang, requiring a reboot. If, for some reason, you do want to use the LIDT instruction, you can only do so when running in "ring 0", thus, it requires you to write a kernel module.

More details can be found here: http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/index.html